# Ubuntu 14.04 Refuses to Install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 14.04, system-installation

I have tried several times to install Ubuntu using a burned DVD, and each time I get through specific settings. It prompts me to install alongside Windows, and I check yes and hit next.  Every time I have tried to install, it will go to a purple screen and eject the disc as if no install actually occurred. Press a button, and it will boot to Windows with no trace of an Ubuntu installation. I tried with and without `nodomoset`, to no luck.

I have md5 checked the disc and there seem to be no errors.  I have even installed on another computer with no issues using the same disc. I have no idea what can be so wrong with my computer.

HP Pavillion m6 
CPU:Intel i5-3210M
HDD: 750 GB (54% used)
RAM: 8 GB
OS: Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: This is usually an issue with your BIOS. Boot to your bios and in the security (uefi) section select to boot Ubuntu rather then Windows.

Comment: did you mean `nomodeset`? For installing beside windows 8, you need to disable secure boot and other stuff - see [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/178596). You also need 64bit ubuntu if it is 64bit windows, which goes for 32bit ubuntu + 32bit windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently happening to me, but until the answer is posted, when your computer boots up, press esc. Press the button next to "Boot Devices" or F9 and select "ubuntu" from the menu, press enter, then you should be okay! If the ubuntu option shows 2 options, try both. If nothing happens on any of the options, I don't know what to say.